# как в django проверить соответствие продукта требованиям покупателя

Tags: python, django, django-model

У меня вопрос по огранизации бизнес логики в django приложении.Есть товар-Model1 с перечнем характеристик, допустим a,b,c и есть покупатели-Model2 у которых эти характеристики строго нормируются, н.п customer1 a1=5, b=7, c=green. Вопрос заключается в следующем как организовать проверку на предмет совпадения характеристик товара со спекой покупателя. Если устанавливать связь многие ко многим, то я так понимаю мне придётся каждый раз при создании нового товара добавлять вручную всех покупателей, что крайне не удобно. А других путей я не вижу, посоветуйте пожалуйста в каком направлении нужно смотреть, что бы реализовать подобную логику

Comment: Кажется, вы уже задавали вопрос здесь ["Проверка на соответствие djang"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1250095/Проверка-на-соответствие-django). Только здесь, по моему скромному мнению, еще менее понятно получилось. Давайте представим, что вы уже реализовали желаемую логику, что это вам дает? Какую проблему в своем проекте вы решили? Опишите, пожалуйста, с точки зрения клиента, что он делает и что он получает, абстрагируясь от возможных деталей реализации.

Comment: Да, всё верно , возможно там я не совсем ясно выразился и поэтому решил переформулировать его иным способом. "Есть товар и есть купец"(ы).мы производим продукт котрый потенциально могут приобрести Mars, Nestle, Royal-Canin. У продукта есть цвет, жирность, содержание белка и.т.д а у покупателей данные параметры строго нормируются и как связать эти сущности я никак не пойму. Хотя вопрос этот самый банальный и вполне жизненный, но ответ на него я никак не могу найти.

Comment: или даже если взять хотя бы один показатель н.п жирность .Пусть в готовом продукте у нас получилось 18, а у Nestle по спецификации она не должна быть выше 20, у Mars не более 14, у Royal-canin 40. То соответственно её можно отправлять в Nestle и Royal , а в Mars будет превышение и товар вернут, она не пройдет у них .Делают такие вещи на уровне запросов или можно на уровне логики модели сделать , не попадаются мне такие примеры

Comment: @artur уточняйте вопрос не в комментариях, а кнопкой "править". Чтоб целостный вопрос был сформулирован там, а не нужно было читать комментарии, чтобы его понять.